# Is there a "Reload changed classes" when debbugging a dart application?

Tags: class, dart, debugging, intellij-idea, reload

Is there a "Reload changed classes" when debbugging a dart application?
I mean the application runs in debug mode in the Dart VM, so there should be something similar to Java. I use IntelliJ IDEA for coding. With Java, I have the option.

Comment: In the Dart world, the feature is called Hot Reload. It is implemented for Flutter projects, but not for the Dart command line applications.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I wanted to know if there is something like this for dart command line applications.